# Convert to mm/dd/yyyy and select max value

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2014, I have a date field named `LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE` that is stored as datetime.

I used the CONVERT function to convert to `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
convert(date,LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE,101) as BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE
```

What I want to be able to do is then select the `MAX` value of `BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE` without creating a table. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why are you wanting to convert it to a string, and *then* find the `MAX`?  If it's stored as a `DATETIME`, just do `MAX(LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE)`.

Comment: sure, just wrap that in max()

Comment: If I don't convert, then I get every record and not the max value.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say `last_baseline_update_date` is a date field. Then you're converting it to... `date` again? Is your intent to convert it to a string?

Comment: The conversion has nothing to do with getting every record or the max. It's the `max()` function which is going to aggregate your data.

Comment: Are you trying to get the MAX based on date or the MAX based the text string? (hint... they ain't the same)

Comment: I'm trying to get the MAX based on date.

Comment: What is the data type of `LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE` and what data type do you expect the output to be? (i.e. a `date` or a string in the form `mm/dd/yyyy`)? I only ask because your conversion doesn't seem to be doing anything if the column is actually already a `date`.

Comment: @LisaRose Then you don't need to mess with conversions at all, just do `SELECT MAX(LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE) FROM YourTable`

Comment: I thought would work too but just selecting the MAX of LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE returns other values than just the max.

Comment: @LisaRose Please show the *exact*, full, query you're using.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unclear from your post what your data is and what you're trying to get out. Here are a couple solutions, hopefully one of which is applicable

Assuming you want your result as a string formatted mm/dd/yyyy you can do this

```
select convert(varchar(10), max(LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE), 101))
from YourTable
```

If you just need it as a date, just do

```
select max(LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE)
from YourTable
```

if `LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE` *is already* a string (formatted mm/dd/yyyy) and you want it as a date,

```
select max(convert(date, LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE, 101))
from YourTable
```

Comment: After some more digging, I see the properties for LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE is datetime, the length is 8 but the Numeric Precision is 23. I'm guessing that's why MAX isn't working as I expected it to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are complicating this. Just do the conversion on the max datetime values.

```
declare @table table (LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE datetime)
insert into @table
values
('20160701 12:21'),
('20160705 03:21'),
('20160401 19:21'),
('20161201 04:21')

select
    convert(varchar(10),max(LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE),101)
from
    @table
```

This method converts your single returned row, which is the max() value of your datetime columns, as opposed to converting every row and *then* finding the max value.

Comment: Seems simple but none of these options are working, It could be the way the data is really being stored. If I store the data in a temporary table and then use select LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE = (Select MAX(LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE) from temporary table then it works correctly. Just trying to figure out why I would have to store the data in a temporary table before the max works correctly.

Comment: @LisaRose well, if the datatype is datetime my solution will work. I've provided a sample. Are you storing it as a varchar?